# CKEditor4.x: Disallow one tag inside an other

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I started using CKEditor 4.x recently, but I want that the user can only use a very limited set of tags. Also not all combinations of tags are useful.

I only allow these tags/formats currently:

```
<p>, <h3>, <ul>, <ol>, <li>, <strong>, <em> (and maybe some more)
```

I only need, that lists are made for normal style and not headlines. But it is absolutely possible to create a headline inside a list element. The result looks funny, but is not useful. The list (dot or numbering) is styled as normal text, but the headline text like a headline (different font, different fontsize, different color).

I want to prohibit this. Also I found out, that in some cases, CKEditor also puts `<p>` tags inside a list, what I also don't want. I guess, it happens mainly, when I change a headline inside a list back to normal, than CKEditor just changes the headline tags to `<p>`.

Is there a possibility, to prevent CKEditor 4 from doing this? I saw, that there even was a ticket about a similar problem for CKEditor 3:

http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/6849

But since CKEditor 4 seems to be a rewrite, the solution seems not to be applicable (it was closed as fixed).

Does anybody know, how I can prevent this? To make it more clear: It is not about pasted text or source editing, I limited the editor very much and the pane contains merely these styles and undo/redo. But still, with the normal commands it is possible to create such unwanted styling.

What I want is:

```
<h3>A simple headline</h3>
<p>A simple paragraph</p>
<ul>
    <li>First text</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

What I **not** want is:

```
<ul>
    <li><p>First text</p></li>
    ...
```

or even:

```
<ul>
    <li><h3>First text</h3></li>
    ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to achieve this easily. The reason is that there are many ways to create this content. List can be pasted, heading can be created in a list item, list can be created on a heading, perhaps you can do this with delete, drag and drop, etc. It is possible to handle all those cases and prevent creating these structures, but that would be a lot of work.

Instead, I think that you could style `li>p, li>h3` in a way that the inner blocks will not be visible (no margins, the same font size) inside editor. Then, you can also apply these styles on a page where you display that content or you can clean the content when retrieving it from the editor. The latter could be done e.g. in this way (see the [`editor#toDataFormat` event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-toDataFormat)):

```js
editor.on( 'toDataFormat', function( evt ) {
    var filter = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.filter( {
        elements: {
            p: function( el ) {
                if ( el.parent && el.parent.name == 'li' ) {
                    delete el.name; // This removes the element and leaves its content.
                }
            }
        }
    } );

    filter.applyTo( evt.data.dataValue );
}, null, 12 );
```

Comment: Wow, that is a really detailed answer! Thank you very much! I understand, that it is no easy task to limit some things on a complex Editor. I already limited the editor in some ways ... since I prohibited the drop event, so no images and other stuff can be dropped. But still there might be some possibilities. I thought, there would be some way to do it. But your solution can also very much help me! So, I have to fetch the content from CKEDITOR itself (currently I use $(...).html() )? Can you just give me the name or link to the API method?